# activemq network of broker messages not flowing

Tags: activemq

activemq 5.12

Network of broker configuration: hub, spoke1, spoke2

spoke1 has duplex n/w connection to hub spoke2 has duplex network connection to hub

I use the following to produce on spoke1

bin/activemq producer --brokerurl tcp://0.0.0.0:61616 --destination queue://producer-214 --messagecount 100 --message "hi there"
Then on spoke2, I try to consume messages

bin/activemq consumer --brokerUrl tcp://0.0.0.0:61616 --destination queue://producer-214
I can see that 100 messages are enqueued on spoke1, but my consumer doesnt see any of the messages and just waits like so

INFO | Connecting to URL: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616 (null:null)
INFO | Consuming queue://producer-214
INFO | Sleeping between receives 0 ms
INFO | Running 1 parallel threads
INFO | consumer-1 wait until 1000 messages are consumed
My configuration for spoke1/2 is identical except for brokername. following is config for spoke2 :

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties
    

 element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
-->

```
<destinationPolicy>
    <policyMap>
      <policyEntries>
        <policyEntry topic=">" >
            <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                 slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                 by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                 For more information, see:

                 http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

            -->
          <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
            <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
          </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
        </policyEntry>
      </policyEntries>
    </policyMap>
</destinationPolicy>
```

```
<networkConnectors>
    <networkConnector uri="static:(tcp://172.31.10.24:61616)?transport.useInactivityMonitor=false" duplex="true"/>
</networkConnectors>

<!--
    Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
    mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
    For more information, see:

    http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
-->
<persistenceAdapter>
    <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
</persistenceAdapter>


  <!--
    The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
    use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
    http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
  -->
  <systemUsage>
    <systemUsage>
        <memoryUsage>
            <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
        </memoryUsage>
        <storeUsage>
            <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
        </storeUsage>
        <tempUsage>
            <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
        </tempUsage>
    </systemUsage>
</systemUsage>
<transportConnectors>
    <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>

<!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
<shutdownHooks>
    <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
</shutdownHooks>
```

```
Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
-->
<import resource="jetty.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The issue was I had networkTTL=1 as soon as I made networkTTL=2 in the metwork connector, messages could be read from spoke2

Thank You